# dont delete non-project folders on deployment aspnetcompiler

Tags: c#-4.0, msbuild, web-deployment, web-deployment-project

The msbuild project has the following aspnetcompiler item

```
        <AspNetCompiler
                VirtualPath = "DeployTemp" 
                PhysicalPath = "..\src\external\Client1\"
                TargetPath = "$(CompileOutputDir)\ClientPages\Client1\"
                Force = "true"
                Debug = "true"
                Updateable = "true"
                ToolPath="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\"/>
```

THe way my application works is, users can upload pictures. The pictures are saved in a folder called *pet_pics* (which is at the same level as the web.config).

If I redeploy using the above msbuild project, the folder *pet_pics* gets deleted and all the pics are lost. Is there a way to configure the msbuild, such that it deploys the project files and does not delete any non-project files?

Comment: You're learning that you don't want to have your upload folder within the path of your web site. Move it outside.

Comment: true. Just that I cannot touch the existing code that I inherited. But i have to automate the deployment.